# Django: Two projects from landing page

Tags: django, apache, django-urls, multi-project

I am planning on a Django multi-project system, where I'll have a Django project hosting the landing page. Then I wish to have two links to two of the separate django projects (maybe that can grow to three in future).

Now, I saw the apache config part in SO as well as in google. But I want to know, what should be the link be in the two buttons on the landing page, as in how would the url pattern be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they're totally separate projects (not separate *apps*, but separate projects), you won't be able to use the `{% url %}` filter. Just hardcode the URL in the templates.

Or you could store the URLs in the database, so you can update them without having to re-deploy the application. Either way, though, the URLs will have to be hardcoded.

Comment: Thanks mipadi,. Yes thes are two "Separate projects" not apps. But isn't hard-coding very bad? Can't I store it in a .py file and import it in template and use from there? Just in case something happens in future.

Comment: @SG2791: Yes, you could put it in the settings.py file, sure.